# Compare sentences in Lists A, B, and amend word in B if not matching.

Tags: python, string, list, set

New to python and I have the below problem, I want to compare two lists, A and B, which they contain sentences. If a word in B, does not exist in A, I want to replace that word in B, with 'foo'. Either in a new list or the current list B.

Example:

```
ListA = ["I am Sam"]
ListB = ["I am Sam", "Yes me Sam"]
```

I would like to get:

```
NewList = ["I am Sam", "foo foo Sam"]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `set` and then a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

ListA = ["I am Sam"]
ListB = ["I am Sam", "Yes me Sam"]

words = set(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, ListA)))

ListB = [' '.join(i if i in words else 'foo' for i in item.split()) for item in ListB]

['I am Sam', 'foo foo Sam']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
ListA = ["I am Sam"]
ListB = ["I am Sam", "Yes me Sam"]
words = set(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, ListA)))
ListB = [' '.join(i if i in words else 'foo' for i in item.split()) for item in ListB]
['I am Sam', 'foo foo Sam']
```

Try this: First use ***set*** and then try to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

```
# two list from the question
ListA = ["I am Sam"]
ListB = ["I am Sam", "Yes me Sam"]

# use set() to collect unique words in ListA    
setA = set([word for i in range(len(ListA)) for word in ListA[i].split(' ')])

# looping ListB and compare each word of each sentence in ListB with ListA
ListB = [word if word in setA else 'foo' for i in range(len(ListB)) for word in ListB[i].split()]

print(ListB)
```

This outputs:

```
['I am Sam', 'foo foo Sam']
```

Comment: Thank you, Sean, for the reminder. Comments have been added to the code.

Comment: Thank you for this and the comments! Very useful!